# Oracle EPRD R12.1.3 connection lost

Tags: java, oracle, ssl

We are using Oracle database EPRD 12.1.3 in our company and all the time we are disconnected. Does anyone know what to do in order to prevent Oracle loosing the connection.

```
proxyHost=null
proxyPort=0
connectMode=HTTPS, native.
Version von Forms-Applet: 10.1.2.3
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
at oracle.forms.net.HTTPNStream.connect(Unknown Source)
at oracle.forms.net.HTTPNStream.doFlush(Unknown Source)
at oracle.forms.net.HTTPNStream.flush(Unknown Source)
at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
at oracle.forms.net.StreamMessageWriter.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
... 13 more
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(Unknown Source)
at oracle.forms.engine.Message.readDetails(Unknown Source)
at oracle.forms.engine.Message.readDetails(Unknown Source)
at oracle.forms.net.StreamMessageReader.run(Unknown Source)
```

Many thanks,
Daniel